# Make hf clickable in WebView

Tags: android

I have this code and I'm trying to make this "here." clickable:

```
// this is the html code in the file
"<a href=\'https://secfirst.org/terms\'>here.</a>"
//Load my html file    
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/terms.html");
```

The webview is loaded well but when I click on "here." there is a error message:

```
WebPage Not available
The webpage at file:///android_res/drawable/terms.html
could not be loaded because: net::: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I know the error is `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` but It probably happens because of the url isn't working. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: try changing `"<a href=\'https://secfirst.org/terms\'>here.</a>"` to `<a href="https://secfirst.org/terms">here.</a>`

Comment: @petey it works well. I need a coffee lol

Comment: hehe,  happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
"<a href=\'https://secfirst.org/terms\'>here.</a>"`
```

to

```
<a href="https://secfirst.org/terms">here.</a>
```

The reason is your html is not valid as the double quotes will be treated as text characters and the rest of your html that uses single quotes do not need to be escaped here. So replacing the slash characters with the single quote (`\'`) for normal double quotes (`"`) would set this right.